# Best design for storing related things

Tags: php, mysql, symfony, doctrine-orm

I am working on an online recipe book, in which there are many recipes, ingredients, categories etc. I have to implement that the admin can add related recipes to objects of given entities(e.g. a category has many related recipes, which according to my client's wish should be added manually). Also, the related recipes have to have an order, which is also set manually. So I need one ManyToMany relationship between recipes and each of other entities(category, ingredient, recipe, etc.), and additionally I have to store the position of each related recipe.

One solution could be to set up a table for each entity having related recipes, and each row would contain an id for the entity, a recipe id and a position. This would mean I would have as many tables as many entities I have with relative recipes, which does not seem to be the best solution.

Another solution could be to have 1 table containing all the information about related recipes, then each row would additionally contain the type of the other entity. Also I am really strict about the DRY principle so I would want to achieve this without writing repeated code and use Doctrine2+Symfony2 to handle as much work as possible.

And if possible, the best would be if I had a piece of code(such as a class) which I can reuse and add the related recipes feature to new entites as well without writing or copy-pasting much code.

What could be the best class/database design for this? I am highlighting, I am using Doctrine2 + Symfony2 so please try to "think in Doctrine".

Thank you in advance!

Comment: by think in doctrine do you mean dql or more like java hibernate emulation? :)

Comment: I mean, that doctrine has many features for implementing database design

Comment: @David Frank: Yes doctrine has, but how is that actually related to your question? I'd say it's much too broad so leads to discussion and can't be answered.

Comment: @hakre Actually Im asking for a method for storing related things for many entites without repeating code. It can be answered.

Comment: Which code do you repeat right now? Normally you do prevent the repetition of code by removing duplicate code, e.g. [Extract Method Refactoring](http://martinfowler.com/refactoring/catalog/extractMethod.html).

Comment: If I create a CategoryRelatedRecipes entity, a RecipeRelatedRecipes entity, an IngredientRelatedRecipes entity, ..., XXXXRelatedRecipes entity, I'm creating entities with the exact same structure. Each will contain the position, the recipe id, and the id of the category, ingredient etc. And also, I will have an additional table for each.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would create the following tables:

```
category
--------
id
name

category_recipe
---------------
category_id
recipe_id
display_order (integer)

recipe
------
id
name
instructions

recipe_ingredient
-----------------
recipe_id
display_order (integer)
name
amount
unit

recipe_related
--------------
recipe_id
related_recipe_id
display_order

user_recipe
-----------
user_id
recipe_id
display_order
```

For the category relationship, you'll have to do a little more work because of the extra display order value in the reference table. Instead of just adding a recipe to a category, you'll need to create RecipeCategory object, set the id values, set the display order, and then save it. Doctrine will still be able to create relationships between these tables, it just requires a little more manual work.

I hope that helps get you on the right path.

Comment: Thank you for the answer. I think you have misunderstood my problem. Actually, I already have these tables, but what I want to achieve is storing related recipes. So even recipes have to have a ManyToMany relationship with recipes because each recipe will have related recipes. So this differs from having ingredients for recipes(which I already have). This means that even such a recipe can be related to an ingredient which does not contain that ingredient, so this has to be different from the ingredient which the recipe contains. Its the same for categories.

Comment: Also, I would like to have a solution which does not need a table containing related recipes for every new entity(so if I add related recipes to e.g. users in the future, I want to do it without copy-pasting code). And what I think the most about is the class design, so I dont have to repeat this related thing for every class.

Comment: It sounds like you don't want to create relationship tables for each type of relationship. I don't suggest doing this, but you could create a single table to maintain all relationships. It would have an id, a target_id, and a type. To link a user to a recipe, you would insert (user_id, recipe_id, "user_recipe"). Doctrine will have difficulty joining these tables automatically because of the type field. I added a recipe_related and a user_recipe table to my answer. That is the approach I suggest. Doctrine should generate these classes, so you don't have to worry about copying similar code.

Comment: So you are suggesting creating an additional entity for every entity for which I want related recipes? Doesnt this kick the DRY rule?

Comment: I don't think this violates the DRY principle, but I can see where you are coming from. I'm not sure the DRY principle is easily applied to structured data like this. It works better for business logic. Dave Thomas has some interesting comments about this here: http://www.artima.com/intv/dry.html

Comment: Is it normal that I have to insert a new file of ~25 lines of code for every entity and all these new files differ in 1-2 lines? Moreover it creates an additional database table for every entity.

Comment: You should be able to use Doctrine to generate those files for you if you're using a YAML file to define your schema.

Comment: It's no problem for me to create those files, I'm just not sure if it's the best solution to have +1 class for each instead of having 1 class which handles all the work in some magical way.